# Raspberry pi B+ freezing while update

Tags: raspbian

It's already 2nd time of same occurrence. I was performing `sudo apt-get update` and in the middle of downloading package, it freezes. Is this a device problem or some kind of my setting problem?

All I have on the pi is raspbian with wifi and bluetooth dongles. Nothing else is there. Freshly installed NOOBS with class 10 SC card.

Comment: What are the specifics of your power supply? I had a similar problem a while back where it seemed to always hang up during updates, but it turned out to be a power supply problem. And on one of my rPi's it was actually caused by a capacitor "tombstoning" on the board - which I fixed by resoldering the cap. Net, the power supply might not be up to par for powering the rPi and the 2 dongles

Comment: I am just using my cell phone charger.
Input = 100-240V 0.15A
Output =  5.0 V 1A

Comment: After trying update several times, it finally finished... i still don't like the idea that it's freezing on me... =/

Comment: Likely because 1A is not giving enough juice for the biggest power needs the Pi has during that operation. You might want to look for a bit stronger supply ... like 1.5A or more.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like it's power issue. I just noticed from another video about it. It was actually suggesting for 2A output. hum...

Comment: 2A is recommended for an rPi2 ... 1.5A should be enough for an rPi B+, but it doesn't hurt to go for higher A's :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning our conversation from comments into a formal answer: Issues with freezing, even if the rPi has been running for a while, typically have one of two reasons:

1. Most common: Your power supply is underpowered. The power needs of the Pi fluctuate, and it needs more power if there are USB peripherals attached. How much depends on the peripherals themselves. During peak usage, the Pi might need more power than during startup, which can lead to brown-outs (freezes). For a model A/B/A+/B+, a 1.5A 5V supply should be enough, for a model 2 you need at least 2A 5V.
2. Some boards, especially early boards, have a capacitor that tends to tomb-stone (where the solder joint on one side is weak and detaches after some use). The capacitor in question is C51 at the underside of the board, near the crystal marked X1. When it tombstones, you will find that USB input devices no longer work, and that the board freezes after 20-60 seconds. The resolution here is to either resolder the (super-tiny!) cap onto its pads, or put a new cap across the two legs of the crystal just above it. This technique has revived one of my model B boards in the past.